# REGEX converting $_POST['x'] to $_x

Tags: php, regex, eclipse, ide

Someone can help me how to make a regular expression to convert all strings like:

```
$_POST['key']
```

To:

```
$_key
```

This will not be used in the code itself, but I will use it in my IDE, to facilitate a bulk change.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do something like:

```
\$_[A-Z].*\['(\w.*)']
```

Replacing it with:

```
$_$1
```

Tested on Sublime Text 3 with the following data:

```
$_POST['key']
$_POST['asd']
$_POST['ser']
$_POST['fsdf']
$_POST['kefas23y']
$_GET['key']
$_GET['asd']
$_GET['ser']
$_GET['fsdf']
$_GET['kefas23y']
```

Output:

```
$_key
$_asd
$_ser
$_fsdf
$_kefas23y
$_key
$_asd
$_ser
$_fsdf
$_kefas23y
```

Explanation:

`\$` - Escape the dollar sign as it's a regex special character

`[A-Z].*` - Assuming only PHP Superglobals being replaced, look for any number of capital letters

`\['(\w.*)']` - Create a group of any number of word characters within single quotations and brackets

`$_$1` - Replace the text with literal `$_` followed by the first group matched in the line - The text in brackets

Comment: Thanks! I adapted your solution to: `\$_POST.*?\['(\w.*?)']`